# Windows 10 app C# tcp client

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I've created a `Arduino + windows 10` app. The microcontroller connects with a Wi-Fi module (ESP8266-ESP01), tcp/ip protocol. The module is the server and app is the client. The module works fine and I tested it on another program ("SocketTest v3.0"). It sends and receives data. But my app can only write data, the socket.InputStream doesn't work. When I read data, it throws an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Maybe there is an example like this program:

[image].

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    StreamSocket _socket;
    HostName _hostName;
    DataWriter writer;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _socket = new StreamSocket();
    }
    private async void connectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        #region _check_parameters
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName_Box.Text))
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Set the Host Name !!!\n";
            return;
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceName_Box.Text))
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Set the Service Name !!!\n";
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            _hostName = new HostName(hostName_Box.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Invalid Host Name !!!\n";
            return;
        }
        #endregion
        // If necessary, tweak the socket's control options before carrying out the connect operation.
        // Refer to the StreamSocketControl class' MSDN documentation for the full list of control options.
        _socket.Control.KeepAlive = false;
        try
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "Connecting...\n";
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(_hostName, serviceName_Box.Text);
            _statusBar.Text += "Connected\n";

            // go to send mode
            connectButton.Content = "Send";
            connectButton.Click -= connectButton_Click;
            connectButton.Click += send_Data;
            hostName_Box.PlaceholderText = "data to send";
            hostName_Box.Text = "";
            writer = new DataWriter(_socket.OutputStream);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Connect failed with error:\n" + exception.Message + "\n";
        }
    }
    private async void read_data()
    {
        DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(_socket.InputStream);
        dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        try
        {
            await dataReader.LoadAsync(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
            string s;
            uint length;
            length = dataReader.ReadUInt32();
            s = dataReader.ReadString(length);
            _statusBar.Text += "Read successful\n" + s + "\n";
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Fail to load dada !!!\n" +
                exception.Message + "\n";
        }
    }

    private async void send_Data(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName_Box.Text))
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "Write anything\n";
            return;
        }
        if(hostName_Box.Text == "read")
        {
            try
            {
                hostName_Box.Text = "";
                read_data();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Reading data failed:\n" + ex.Message + "\n";
            }
        }
        writer.WriteUInt32(writer.MeasureString(hostName_Box.Text));
        writer.WriteString(hostName_Box.Text);
        try
        {
            await writer.StoreAsync();
            _statusBar.Text += "\"" + hostName_Box.Text + "\" sent successfully\n";
            hostName_Box.Text = "";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(ex.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Send failed with error:\n" + ex.Message + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe my reading function is not so good, but the error is that in every situation

```
dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength == 0;
```

and when I use:

```
int length = dataReader.ReadInt32();
```

it throws an exception.

Comment: Please quote the errors/exceptions you get.

Comment: The first error is that the dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength == 0. And the function .LoadAsync(...) throws the error. If I send a string "qwerty" and do dataReader.LoadAsync(6) it throws --> "The operation attempted to acces data outside the valid range"

Comment: Is there a firewall on the client that could be causing issues?

Comment: I don't think so, I checked the connection, data read and write on another app and it works

Answer (score 0):

> The first error is that the dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength == 0. And the function .LoadAsync(...) throws the error.

[DataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) is used to get the size of the **buffer** that has not been read. You **haven't loaded any data** from the input stream **to the intermediate buffer** before you called `dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength`, so the value is 0. And the parameter of  [DataReader.LoadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.LoadAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)  cannot be zero, so you got a System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.

> If I send a string "qwerty" and do dataReader.LoadAsync(6) it throws --> "The operation attempted to acces data outside the valid range"

This exception is thrown by the code `s = dataReader.ReadString(length);`, you need to call `await dataReader.LoadAsync(length);` to load the string data into the buffer before you can read it.

Following is the sample code I have verified:

```
private async void read_data()
{
    DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(_socket.InputStream);
    dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
    try
    {
        //load some data to the buffer first
        await dataReader.LoadAsync(4);
        //read int data
        uint length = dataReader.ReadUInt32();
        //load data to the buffer before reading it.
        uint acturalStringLength = await dataReader.LoadAsync(length);
        //read string data
        string s = dataReader.ReadString(acturalStringLength);
        _statusBar.Text += "Read successful\n" + s + "\n";
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Fail to load dada !!!\n" +
            exception.Message + "\n";
    }
}
```